# Trying to build the open source Signal iOS app and connect to my own server

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to build the Signal iOS app to connect to my own Signal server.

I have already successfully built the Signal Android app to connect to my own server.

For both I followed the article,
https://github.com/madeindra/setup-guide/tree/master/signal-ios

Using Signal iOS build 3.13.2.6
XCode 12

I was able to get the app to build in XCode after some effort.
The app ran, got through the verify phone number screen (so I assume was able to hit our server successfully and I got the SMS message through Twilio)
Next was the User info screen asking for name, this crashed with this error,

```
**Fatal error: [OWSUploadV2.swift:78 upload(data:uploadForm:uploadUrlPath:progressBlock:)]: Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://xxx.cloudfront.net/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://xxx.cloudfront.net/, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(**
**"LocalUploadTask <2455BE4E-077E-4FD5-B8FA-7F03FD733F70>.<1>"**
**), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalUploadTask <2455BE4E-077E-4FD5-B8FA-7F03FD733F70>.<1>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}: file SignalCoreKit/OWSSwiftUtils.swift, line 35**
```

This seemed to be some kind of SSL issue, although opening the cloudfront URL in a browser or in the Android app did not have any issues.

I added the code to OWSUploadV2.swift,

```
class func upload(data: Data,... {
        var uploadSessionManager = self.uploadSessionManager
        let securityPolicy = AFSecurityPolicy(pinningMode: AFSSLPinningMode.none)
            securityPolicy.validatesDomainName = false
            securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = true
        uploadSessionManager.securityPolicy = securityPolicy
```

and this seemed to solve the issue, but not sure why the issue occurred...

so this gets me to the next screen for entering a PIN, but this crashed with the error,

```
**2020-10-08 14:22:10:284 Signal[4202:2191958]**  **[OWSWebSocket.m:605 -[OWSWebSocket processWebSocketResponseMessageAsync:]]: received WebSocket response requestId: 7765599138296075969, status: 200**
**2020-10-08 14:22:10:287 Signal[4202:2191848]** ❤️ **[VersionedProfilesImpl.swift:234 didFetchProfile(profile:profileRequest:)]: Invalid credential: VerificationFailed.**
**Fatal error: [VersionedProfilesImpl.swift:234 didFetchProfile(profile:profileRequest:)]: Invalid credential: VerificationFailed.: file SignalCoreKit/OWSSwiftUtils.swift, line 35**
```

This is where I am stuck. Anyone have any ideas?
Has anyone else successfully got Signal iOS connecting to their own server?

*** some more info

So this error occurs in line 234 of VersionedProfilesImpl.swift didFetchProfile()

```
in receiveProfileKeyCredential()

let credentialResponse = try ProfileKeyCredentialResponse(contents: UInt8)
let clientZkProfileOperations = try self.clientZkProfileOperations()
let profileKeyCredential = try clientZkProfileOperations.receiveProfileKeyCredential(profileKeyCredentialRequestContext: requestContext, profileKeyCredentialResponse: credentialResponse)
```

In the server logs I see,

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2020:14:40:50 +0000] “GET /v1/accounts/apn/preauth/3d80bda824920abd18b41aee5bb2559e01545705d52e7e00da49f3a43a745d96/+16137966017 HTTP/1.1” 200 0 “-” “Signal/3.13.2 (iPhone; iOS 13.7; Scale/2.00)” 9
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2020:14:40:50 +0000] “GET /v1/accounts/sms/code/+16137966017?client=ios HTTP/1.1” 200 0 “-” “Signal/3.13.2 (iPhone; iOS 13.7; Scale/2.00)” 11
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2020:14:41:21 +0000] “PUT /v1/accounts/code/443388?transfer=true HTTP/1.1” 200 70 “-” “Signal/3.13.2 (iPhone; iOS 13.7; Scale/2.00)” 153
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2020:14:41:21 +0000] “PUT /v1/accounts/attributes/ HTTP/1.1” 204 0 “-” “Signal/3.13.2 (iPhone; iOS 13.7; Scale/2.00)” 96
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2020:14:41:21 +0000] “PUT /v2/keys HTTP/1.1” 204 0 “-” “Signal/3.13.2 (iPhone; iOS 13.7; Scale/2.00)” 24
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2020:14:41:22 +0000] “PUT /v1/accounts/apn HTTP/1.1” 204 0 “-” “Signal/3.13.2 (iPhone; iOS 13.7; Scale/2.00)” 111
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2020:14:41:22 +0000] “GET /v1/profile/1337589b-38e8-4d09-9ae1-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 HTTP/1.1” 200 281 “-” “Signal/3.13.2 (iPhone; iOS 13.7; Scale/2.00)” 110
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2020:14:41:22 +0000] “GET /v1/config/ HTTP/1.1” 200 13 “-” “Signal/3.13.2 (iPhone; iOS 13.7; Scale/2.00)” 140
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2020:14:41:22 +0000] “GET /v1/websocket/?login=1337589B-38E8-4D09-9AE1-0C362B94EF42&password=0f9a8ed6a5909226b76f520fe7181447 HTTP/1.1” 101 0 “-” “-” 6
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2020:14:41:22 +0000] “GET /v1/certificate/delivery?includeUuid=true HTTP/1.1” 200 386 “-” “Signal/3.13.2 (iPhone; iOS 13.7; Scale/2.00)” 2
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2020:14:41:22 +0000] “PUT /v1/directory/tokens HTTP/1.1” 200 173 “-” “Signal/3.13.2 (iPhone; iOS 13.7; Scale/2.00)” 9
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2020:14:41:22 +0000] “GET /v2/attachments/form/upload HTTP/1.1” 200 908 “-” “Signal/3.13.2 (iPhone; iOS 13.7; Scale/2.00)” 117
174.112.230.123 - - [16/Oct/2020:14:41:23 +0000] “GET /v2/attachments/form/upload WS” 200 911 “-” “-”
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2020:14:41:23 +0000] “GET /v1/certificate/delivery?includeUuid=true HTTP/1.1” 200 386 “-” “Signal/3.13.2 (iPhone; iOS 13.7; Scale/2.00)” 3
174.112.230.123 - - [16/Oct/2020:14:41:23 +0000] “PUT /v1/messages/1337589B-38E8-4D09-9AE1-0C362B94EF42 WS” 200 19 “-” “-”
174.112.230.123 - - [16/Oct/2020:14:41:23 +0000] “GET /v2/attachments/form/upload WS” 200 911 “-” “-”
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2020:14:41:23 +0000] “GET /v1/certificate/delivery?includeUuid=true HTTP/1.1” 200 386 “-” “Signal/3.13.2 (iPhone; iOS 13.7; Scale/2.00)” 9
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2020:14:41:24 +0000] “GET /v1/certificate/delivery?includeUuid=true HTTP/1.1” 200 386 “-” “Signal/3.13.2 (iPhone; iOS 13.7; Scale/2.00)” 3
174.112.230.123 - - [16/Oct/2020:14:41:30 +0000] “GET /v2/attachments/form/upload WS” 200 911 “-” “-”
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2020:14:41:30 +0000] “PUT /v1/profile/ HTTP/1.1” 200 0 “-” “Signal/3.13.2 (iPhone; iOS 13.7; Scale/2.00)” 123
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2020:14:41:30 +0000] “GET /v1/certificate/delivery?includeUuid=true HTTP/1.1” 200 386 “-” “Signal/3.13.2 (iPhone; iOS 13.7; Scale/2.00)” 6
174.112.230.123 - - [16/Oct/2020:14:41:30 +0000] “GET /v1/profile/1337589b-38e8-4d09-9ae1-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 WS” 200 997 “-” “-”
```

Any idea what the cause could be?
I can connect from Android to the same server with the same settings.

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to get it to work in the latest XCode.
I think it was meant for XCode 11, so just to get it to compile I had to make changes in,

DebugUIStress.swift

BlurHashEncode.swift

(but if anyone has correct updates to these classes please post)

To get the app to run I made changes in,

OWSUploadV2.swift

- ignored SSL certificate error

ClientZkProfileOperations.swift

- ignored profile credential errors

KeyBackupService.swift

- ignored errors

It is now running, and I can send messages, but still having some issues.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's a problem uploading something to aws cloudfront. It gives you a -999 error. The -999 error is this one:

> -999 is caused by ErrorCancelled. This means: another request is made before the previous request is completed.

Is the program making a request before uploading the profile details to the server?